# jquery get selected value from dropdownlist? Not text

Tags: jquery

How to get value of selected dropdownlist.

Ex.

```
" Text="---Select---" Value="0">"
```

I need value "0".

Thanks,

Comment: could you post the generated html?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

To get value:

```
$('#YourdropDownId').val();
```

To get text:

```
$('#YourdropDownId :selected').text();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('[name="YourdropDownName"] option:selected').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have seen similar answers but `$('#YourdropDownId').val()` never worked for me with jQuery 1.10.2

Instead I have to use `$("select[id*=ddlurgency]").val()` for:

```
<select name="urgency" id="ddlurgency" class="form-control" runat="server">
   <option value="970200000">Not very urgent</option>
   <option value="970200001">Urgent</option>
   <option value="970200002">Very urgent</option>
</select>
```